# Javascript not reacting as expected

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a small problem which I don't even know how to explain. The main thing is that I have two buttons, **one is to open an edit form:**

[image: How the edit layout looks like]

**And another one to delete and item:**
[image: How the delete layout looks like]

Now, the main issue is what and how reacts when I click and where I click. Whenever I click on button to edit (as you can see is has a bit of padding on the sides) the js loads up the edit form that I need, thus calling the function that I indicated it to run whenever a click occurs in the edit "space-area"-button.

Whenever, and here is where the issue arises, I click on the button to delete, and here I mean whenever I click on the trashcan( the `<img>` element itself), it does absolutely nothing, although when I move my mouse outside the blue rectangle (in other words the `<img>` element) and click inside the area that has padding, **THEN** the click calls the function that I need. Above all that, when I click in the "padding area" the `event.target` is for some reason undefined.

I can't seem to really understand the reason of this, thanks for any help.

EDIT: Added JS Code as requested:

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    const eTarget = event.target;
    console.log(event.target);

    switch(true){
        case eTarget.classList.contains('close-edit'):
            editContentContainer.classList.toggle('show');
            break;
        case eTarget.classList.contains('add-data'):
        case eTarget.classList.contains('edit-data'):
        case eTarget.classList.contains('delete-data'):
            asyncCollectAndAction(eTarget.id);            
            break;
        case eTarget.classList.contains('add-new-flavour'):
            addNewFlavourToProduct(eTarget);
            break;
    }
});


const asyncCollectAndAction = (targetID) => {   
    /*
        Action type:
        1 - Insert/Add
        2 - Edit
        3 - Delete
    */ 
   console.log('target Id is: ', targetID);

    let collectedData = '';
    let formCollector = ''
    const categoryType = targetID.split('-')[0];
    const actionType = targetID.split('-')[1];
    console.log('action type is: ', actionType, typeof(actionType), actionType);

    if(actionType != 'delete' || actionType != "delete"){
        formCollector = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-category^=${targetID}`);
    }

}
```

Just to reinforce what I meant, whenever I press on the button to delete (on the element itself), the click is registered by JS (the `console.log(event.target);` outputs the element that I clicked) but it does not call the function `asyncCollectAndAction(eTarget.id);`. Whenever I move outside the element but still inside the bound of the padding (the green area between the margin and the boundaries of the element) only then the function `asyncCollectAndAction(eTarget.id);` is called, but the `event.target` is undefined. This does not happen though when I press on the edit button or element, it seems only to occur on the delete button.

Comment: Could you post some of the script you are having issues with?

Comment: SO where is the actual javascript code that binds the click?

Comment: @JustinPearce edited the code and explained a bit more in detail at the bottom.

Comment: @epascarello added it.

Comment: well event.target is what you click on so if you click the image, it is going to be the image element and not the anchor. So you are going to have to rethink your code.  Might be better off using closest.

Comment: @epascarello exactly, but that is not the case when I click on the edit button. Whenever I click on the <img> element, the function is fired without regard to the anchor, though the same behavior is not repeated for the delete button.

Comment: you code uses `edit-data` but the html shows `edit-product`. Which is the right one ?

Comment: also, your function accepts `e` as the event parameter but you are using the global `event` variable inside the method. Be consistent and use `e` in both cases.

Comment: Finally try with `const eTarget = e.target.closest('a[data-type="product"]');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The target of the event is the img tag, which probably does not have the CSS class your JavaScript is looking for. It sounds like the image is a child node of the anchor tag that has the CSS class. Instead, you need to climb up the document tree starting from the event.target element looking for the CSS class. If the current element doesn't have it, go to the parentNode. Keep going up until the parentNode is null.

Comment: That was my first thought, in climbing up in the DOM tree, but the issue does not occur when I press on the edit button, it reacts like the <img> is not even there, thus my confusion.

Comment: It might work for the edit button if the CSS class is on the img tag.